# Combine 2 MYSQL count queries from same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to create a query that will give me the # of tickets opened & closed in a specified time frame grouped by week.  Does anyone have ideas on how I could accomplish this?

If I change the time reference's from `T1.closed` instead of `T1.opened` I get the right grouping for one column but not the other.

below is what I have so far.

```
SELECT 
FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(T1.created) -MOD(TO_DAYS(T1.created) -1, 7)) as week,
COUNT(T1.created) as Opened, COUNT(T2.ticket) as Closed

FROM issues as T1
LEFT JOIN issues T2 on T1.ticket = T2.ticket AND T1.closed 
BETWEEN (DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 2 MONTH)) 
AND (DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) AND T1.closed IS NOT NULL

WHERE
T1.created > (DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 2 MONTH))
AND
T1.created < (DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH))

GROUP BY
week
```

Comment: Use the `SUM` of a `CASE` statement.  It'll negate the need for the join altogether.  `COUNT` is really not what you need here.  I've found `COUNT` is rarely what you need.

Comment: I will look into how to apply that here.  I am a newbie, but i thought SUM would be looking for #'s in a field to add and being this is time being referenced i wasn't sure that would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand t1.opened and t1.closed are dates, so you can go with:

```
select `week`, sum(`opened`), sum(`closed`) from
(
    select week(t1.opened) as `week`, count(*) as `opened`, 0 as `closed`
    from issues as t1
    where t1.opened is not null AND ##FILTER BY OPENED##
    group by week(t1.opened)
union all
    select week(t2.closed) as `week`, 0 as `opened`, count(*) as `closed`
    from issues as t2
    where t2.closed is not null AND ##FILTER BY CLOSED##
    group by week(t2.closed)
) as t3
group by `week`
```

note: you see that there are 2 queries, do not join them, because there can be weeks without closed/opened issues

note2: if you want to add filter by creation date - you need to think how it should work, for example issue was created 1st january, opened 8th january, closed 15th january, what should be produced what each of these ranges: 1-7, 2-8, 9-16?

Comment: The goal is to be able to filter preferably on a date referenced on both created and closed (these are the only 2 columns).  The above worked and provided me a sum of all tickets open and closed during the week #. I did have to change t1.opened to t1.created as the actual column in the table is called created.

Comment: @user3288534 ok, then just add proper WHERE to each sub-query